# Magento 2, 2 websites, multiple docker containers-speed implications?

Tags: magento2, docker

I currently have a powerful dedicated server hosting 2 websites, we are experiencing CPU overload & clashing on indexing & rewarming FPC, to solve this problem, I am considering breaking out each website into docker containers, with separate containers to handle mysql, cron & varnish...will this alleviate my CPU overload & clashing and will there be any significant reduction in speed on the production websites?
Thank you Bigfella59

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Are you using 2 URL's - so you can keep all the temporary/transient details segregated?  Share the two complete my.cnf   or  my.ini's with us, please.